# Alignment breaks on browser zoom

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can someone help me with this?

When I hover on the icon, it should have a red border below that icon that aligns with the red border below the text. However, it breaks on browser zoom and I have trouble aligning it. Below is the screenshot:

[image]

Below is what I have so far.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu MyMenu-1" style="display: block;">
<li>
    <span data-toggle="MyMenu-1-1" class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right block text-light-black text-light-black"></span>
    <a class="text-light-black" href="#">Menu 1</a>
</li>
<li>
    <span data-toggle="MyMenu-2-1" class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right block text-light-black text-light-black" ></span>
    <a class="text-light-black" href="#">Menu 2</a>
</li>
<li>
    <span data-toggle="MyMenu-3-1" class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right block text-light-black text-light-black"></span>
    <a class="text-light-black active" href="#">Menu 3</a>
</li>
<li>
    <span data-toggle="MyMenu-4-1" class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right block text-light-black text-light-black" ></span>
    <a  class="text-light-black" href="#">Menu 4</a>
</li>
<li>
    <span data-toggle="MyMenu-5-1" class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right block text-light-black text-light-black"></span>
    <a class="text-light-black" href="#">Menu 5</a>
</li></ul>
```

css code

```
.mega-dropdown-menu li {
   list-style: none;
   display: inline-block;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu li span:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #990000;
  border-bottom-width: medium;
  border-color: #990000;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-bottom: 1.8px;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu li span span {
   padding-right: 13px;
}
.text-light-black {
  color: #1a1a1a !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.text-light-black {
  color: #1a1a1a !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  font-size: 20px;
}
 .mega-dropdown-menu > li a:hover, .mega-dropdown-menu > li a.active {
   border-bottom: 2px solid #990000;
   border-bottom-width: medium;
   border-color: #990000;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Note: icon should use different element since it will have another sub menu when clicked while the `a` tag will redirect to another page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some changes on your CSS. see example in jsFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hamzanisar/9ngw397k/5/

```
    <ul class="mega-dropdown-menu MyMenu-1" style="display: block;">
<li>
    <i data-toggle="MyMenu-1-1" class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right block text-light-black text-light-black"></i>
    <a class="text-light-black" href="#">Menu 1</a>
</li>
<li>
    <i data-toggle="MyMenu-2-1" class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right block text-light-black text-light-black" ></i>
    <a class="text-light-black" href="#">Menu 2</a>
</li>
<li>
    <i data-toggle="MyMenu-3-1" class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right block text-light-black text-light-black"></i>
    <a class="text-light-black active" href="#">Menu 3</a>
</li>
<li>
    <i data-toggle="MyMenu-4-1" class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right block text-light-black text-light-black" ></i>
    <a  class="text-light-black" href="#">Menu 4</a>
</li>
<li>
    <i data-toggle="MyMenu-5-1" class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right block text-light-black text-light-black"></i>
    <a class="text-light-black" href="#">Menu 5</a>
</li></ul>
```

**CSS**

```
   .mega-dropdown-menu li {
   list-style: none;
   display: inline-block;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu li i{
   vertical-align: middle;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-width: medium;
      padding-bottom: 1.8px;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu li i:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #990000;
  border-bottom-width: medium;
  border-color: #990000;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

.text-light-black {
  color: #1a1a1a !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.text-light-black {
  color: #1a1a1a !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  font-size: 20px;
}
 .mega-dropdown-menu > li a:hover, .mega-dropdown-menu > li a.active {
   border-bottom: 2px solid #990000;
   border-bottom-width: medium;
   border-color: #990000;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: thanks. however icon should be different since icon has another sub menu when clicked while  `a` tag will redirect to another page. thanks.

Comment: ok it's mean you don't need 'Pseudo-element' so then try this one https://jsfiddle.net/hamzanisar/9ngw397k/5/

Comment: Thanks it works.. please update your answer so I can accept it. thanks.